# Eclipse Helios CDT under Ubuntu 11.04 crashes every time I start it: "A fatal error ... SIGSEGV"

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, helios

Could someone help me with this, I started using Eclipse only few days ago. I did google this problem, I see other people had the same "SIGSERV" crash but I did not find the way to fix it.

Eclipse Helios CDT under Ubuntu 11.04 crashes every time within a few seconds after I start it. It started happening after I cleared the check box: Index source files that are not included in the project.

Below is the error log. It's very long so I posted only the top part it.

THX!!

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff5ccc6cc8b, pid=22977, tid=140693409957632
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.semantics.CPPSemantics.declaredBefore(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/cdt/core/dom/ast/IASTNode;Z)Z
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

> Current thread (0x00000000416bd000): 
>   JavaThread "Worker-7"
>   [_thread_in_Java, id=23044,
>   stack(0x00007ff5bca90000,0x00007ff5bcb91000)]
>
> siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0,
>   si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR),
>   si_addr=0x000000000165657a

Comment: Don't know what the specific cause is, but if it was working previously then can't you just restore to a version from your SCM?  If not first try removing the eclipse specific files (do this without Eclipse running, remove the .project file and .settings directories from within the project) and then import the project in Eclipse. If that doesn't work and you installed from synaptic then do a full clean and reinstall, or if a manual install then try a fresh copy.  Another possible workaround is to try a different JDK, sun 1.5 or jrockit (manual install)

Answer (score 3):

could be several things, you might try out what of my students (Michael Rueegg) figured out during his master's project:

"After an Ubuntu system update on our CI environment, we regularly noticed broken unit tests which were caused by segmentation faults of the JVM. The update included the new JRE version 1.6.0_24.
The reason for this issue is partially described in the CDT bugzilla entry 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333227 . 
The proposed solution is to use a HotSpot option called UseCompressedOops. Oops stands for “ordinary object pointer” and is the equality of a managed pointer in HotSpot [Joh09]. This option is intended to reduce the memory usage of a 64-bit JVM by — among other provisions — encoding 64-bit pointers into 32-bits where possible [Joh09]."

[Joh09]
John Rose.  CompressedOops - HotSpot Internals for OpenJDK. World Wide Web, http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops , 2009. Accessed: 12.06.2011.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had a similar problem with Eclipse Indigo with CDT
I got the solution from here
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/664268/

add the following line to your **eclipse.ini** file

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```